# Is there a select query to grab all but my current selection?

Tags: d3.js

In my d3js app, when the user hovers over a particular circle, I have it enlarge. That is no problem. At the same time, I want to select "all the others" and make them smaller. What is a good query to grab "all the other circles"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) or the lesser known functional form of the commonly used [selection.select](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) depending on your needs.

If you bind your DOM elements to data using [key functions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions), which is the recommended way, then you can filter on a selection's key: http://jsfiddle.net/9TmXs/

```js
.on('click', function (d) {

    // The clicked element returns to its original size
    d3.select(this).transition() // ...

    var circles = d3.selectAll('svg circle');
    // All other elements resize randomly.
    circles.filter(function (x) { return d.id != x.id; })
        .transition() // ...
});
```

Another general approach is comparing the DOM elements themselves: http://jsfiddle.net/FDt8S/

```js
.on('click', function (d) {

    // The clicked element returns to its original size
    d3.select(this).transition() // ..

    var self = this;

    var circles = d3.selectAll('svg circle');
    // All other elements resize randomly.
    circles.filter(function (x) { return self != this; })
        .transition()
        // ...
});
```